# Unused address pins in AVR ATMEGA162

Tags: avr, atmega, sram, tri-state

We have an ATMEGA162, and have connected an SRAM to it. We do not use PC5, that is the 13th address bit. What are we to do with this pin? When we connected it to ground, we got no errors in the SRAM. When we connected it through a 1k resistor, we got some errors.

What is causing this? We think this is a problem since if we put on an address that has the 13th bit high, that would cause a short circuit, which is not good.

Comment: 1K is bit too stiff, try a 47k.

Comment: @Wossname We've tried that too. The problem is that the resistance is to high. The higher the resistance, the higher the error.

Comment: OK, well can you give us a circuit diagram of the area in question and explain more about this error you are experiencing.

Comment: Try tying the SRAM's 13th address bit (and any higher address lines too) hard to GND.  They could be floating around acting like antennas.

Comment: Huh? Tie *output* pins to GND?!

Comment: What do you mean with "we do not *use* PC5"? Are you using address bits #14 and/or #15? Is PC5 connected to the SRAM?

Comment: @JimmyB, the *SRAM*'s address pins will be inputs.

Comment: @Wossname Yeah, ok. I *think* the OP is referring to the *AVR's* PC5 pin, but would need clarification about that and about the SRAM's size and/or connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "Special Function IO Register - `SFIOR`" (bits XMM2, XMM1, XMM0) to reduce the number of address pins used by the XMEM interface.

Alternatively just leave those pins on the AVR unconnected; that should be fine because with XMEM enabled, they are *outputs* only. Under no circumstances should you connect them to Vcc or GND directly, otherwise a single accidental RAM access to the "wrong" RAM address could destroy the AVR.

Tie any unused address pins on the SRAM (inputs) to either Vcc or GND via a pull-up/-down resistor.

Comment: Thank you. We disabled the bit and enabled pull up, but nothing changed. We fixed it by enabling the bits in SFIOR, so that it is not used, and connected the bit to ground. By doing so, the error disappeared.